# oauth2-client for Google working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, oauth, oauth-2.0

Hi got a bit problem and I can't find any lead, here it goes

I'm working with OAuth2-client from [here](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client) and I'm doing it in codeigniter

this is my controller :

```
public function index()
    {
        include(APPPATH.'libraries/League/OAuth2/Client/Provider/IdentityProvider.php');
        include(APPPATH.'libraries/League/OAuth2/Client/Provider/Google.php');
        $provider = new League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google(array(
        'clientId'  =>  '********************.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'clientSecret'  =>  '**************************',
        'redirectUri'   =>  '**************************/oauth2callback'
    ));

    if ( ! isset($_GET['code'])) {

        // If we don't have an authorization code then get one
        $provider->authorize();

    } else {

        try {

            // Try to get an access token (using the authorization code grant)
            $t = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', array('code' => $_GET['code']));

            // NOTE: If you are using Eventbrite you will need to add the grant_type parameter (see below)
            // $t = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', array('code' => $_GET['code'], 'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'));

            try {

                // We got an access token, let's now get the user's details
                $userDetails = $provider->getUserDetails($t);

                foreach ($userDetails as $attribute => $value) {
                    var_dump($attribute, $value) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
                }

            } catch (Exception $e) {

                // Failed to get user details

            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            // Failed to get access token

        }
    }

    }
```

I get the OAuth class and save it to my library folder

Somehow I manage to open the google "Choose Account" or "login" and the request for permission this [image]

but when I click Accept the page reload to this 
 `url https://mysite.com/oauth2callback?state=****&code=***`

and that is 404 in my end.

does anyone have better solution to this, could anyone help me.
this is my 1st try using OAUTH and working in google app engine so please spare me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your app configured to respond to GET requests to https://mysite.com/oauth2callback

Comment: @GwynHowell no, all I have is that code, maybe that's why I got 404 on my end, dunno how to respond to that so..

Comment: I will respond in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user approves the OAuth, Google redirects back to your app with the URL you registered with them, in your case this is /oauth2callback (this is actually the default). It looks as though, from the code you have posted, that the code to deal with this request is in the index() function.

So, to fix you code, you can either move the logic from the index function to a new handler / controller which responds to /oauth2callback, or change the redirectUri, both in your code and at google cloud console to point back to whatever URL calls the index() function.

Comment: what in my mind is create controller and name it oauth2callback.php is that way help?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me

Comment: now I got another issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905105/oauth-2-0-for-google-working-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

404 mean you dont have "oauth2callback" controller or dont have index method in it

callback url is url you can get information requested to oauth provider

I see your url dont have index.php. If normal url of your project have it, you are putting wrong url. Solution is you need to put absolute callback url in callback param by using site_url function

Comment: i try to create oauth2callback controller.

Comment: yes, create it and create method index() in it, you can handle value returned by provider

Comment: somehow i manage to make it work, but i got another error line89 of identityprovider.php 
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Unknown grant "League\OAuth2\Client\Grant\Authorizationcode"'`

Comment: @kodewrecker did you fix your issue? I'm having the same exact error!

Comment: @kodewrecker I've found the problem, is this bug: https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client/issues/79

Comment: @Alain1405 i see that is why, thanks for this man. Is your problem resolve?

Comment: Passing "authorizationCode" instead of "authorization_code" to $token = $provider->getAccessToken(' solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the library, look at this: https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client/issues/90

Anyway, i have the same problem: don't know how to code the callback controller.

Comment: Here's some code:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051160/google-oauth-library-working-in-session-in-mvc-php